# How to automate command prompt action via selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

My project involves sending lots of xml via command prompt and checking those transaction in a web browser. I would like to know how can i use selenium webdriver to automate this steps. Will selenium webdriver able to mimick the command prompt action.?

Comment: Selenium WebDriver only controls the browser. If you use Java / some other capable programming language to write your tests, you send the command line actions via the language and then check in browser via Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

*Will selenium webdriver able to mimick the command prompt action.?*

No. Selenium is a browser mimicking tool. It will not be able to interact with command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is designed to handle only browser. It cant handle objects out side window. You can use other tools like AutoIt to handle objects outside the browser.